# Should I do require('child_process').spawn('node', ['-e', code]) to run a lengthy operation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, spawn

JavaScript doesn't allow multithreading. So I'm wondering if I should use

```
const node = require('child_process').spawn('node', ['-e', code]);
```

Where `code` is the lengthy operation's code I wish to run.

I've tried it and it does work, the main JS program doesn't remain blocked.

I can also use `node.kill()` after a timeout to stop the process.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should not use `child_process` for node processes (unless you really need the OS to manage a separate process for some reason).

To run CPU-intensive JavaScript code without blocking, use [worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html). They have less overhead, simpler communication, and may share memory.

Comment: Since running a child_process would certainly work (as it did just fine before we had worker threads), perhaps you should add to your answer some reasoning/benefits for being so strongly in favor of worker threads.